# How do I import CSV in Cassandra using the Python driver?

Tags: cassandra

I need to import CSV file into cassandra using python driver

```
import csv

with open('place_ratings.csv') as f_in:
   companies = csv.load(f_in)

with open('place_ratings.csv') as f_in:
   companies = csv.reader(f_in)

with open('C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\MonashMRDB_datasets\place_ratings.csv') as f_in:
   companies = csv.reader(f_in)
```

I tried everything above, wil r, rt and almost every option

I still get the error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user_ratings.csv'
```

what could be done here?

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to be the path to the CSV.

Use a forward slash instead which works for both Unix and Windows. For example:

```
C:/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/MonashMRDB_datasets/place_ratings.csv
```

The alternative on Windows is to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
C:\\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\\MonashMRDB_datasets\\place_ratings.csv
```

But the best practice is to use `os.path` so it's guaranteed to work on any platform:

```
os.path.join("C:", "apache-cassandra-3.11.7\MonashMRDB_datasets", "place_ratings.csv")
```

As a side note, writing new code for importing CSVs is reinventing the wheel. I recommend you use the free **DataStax Bulk Loader ([docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/1.9.0/dsbulkAbout.html), [source](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk))** tool (`dsbulk`). DSBulk lets you load/unload data from/to CSV or JSON. Cheers!